# Alert not working what's wrong in this

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I write the following to alert but it is not displaying the alert box what's wrong in this

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    str = "Total Count: '" + click + "'";

    Response.Write("<Script>alert('" + str + "')</script>");
    click = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested single quotes, try without:

```
    str = "Total Count: " + click;
    Response.Write("<Script>alert('" + str + "')</script>");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should escape your apostrophes in the following line:

Change:

```
str = "Total Count: '" + click + "'";
```

To:

```
str = "Total Count: \'" + click + "\'";
```

Comment: yeah, because due to your string concatenation, you'd have ended up with "alert('Total Count''')"

Comment: That's what the OP has written in the question.  Personally, I (and most everyone else, it seems) would leave out the nested quotes but that choice is left up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten the '@' and the ';' characters in the alert function:

Replace this line:

```
Response.Write("<Script>alert('" + str + "')</script>");
```

with this:

```
Response.Write(@"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + str + "');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the signature of your method is Timer1_Tick, I assume you are using ScriptManager. The correct way to inject javascript with ScriptManager is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(this), "alert", "alert('" + str + "');", true)
```